# Javascript download not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, todataurl

I am downloading the image. It is only working in Chrome not in Firefox or IE.

```
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
        a.download = 'Post-ITIE.jpg';
        a.click()
```

Can anyone help me how can it be working for all browsers.

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/52/)

Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: make sure the versions of FF and IE support HTML5

Comment: yup i am using new browsers

Comment: please post the entire code, a snipet would not help much.

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support the `download` attribute (source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download). As for Firefox, it should work but you should provide a completely reproducible code example.

Comment: @DinoMyte check the JsFiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/52/

Comment: works fine for me in FF v45.0.1

Comment: @DinoMyte i have 45.0.2 and it is just taking a screenshot not downloading

Comment: @JonKoops is there way we can download images in IE?

Comment: Maybe if you set `target="blank"` on the link. That should open the link in a new window in browsers that do not support the `download` attribute. Less than ideal, but it beats needing a server.

Comment: ok i sort out how to work in IE. It uses msSaveBlob to download elements but the firefox should work with my code but its not working. Is it working for you?

Comment: @DinoMyte It doesn't download the file in Firefox here. However if I add the link to the DOM before triggering the click it does download the file like expected.

Comment: @JonKoops i added a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');  but it does not work

Comment: You mean that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: its working in IE and for that i added window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Post-IT.jpg');  but it is not working in firefox

Comment: Obviously that doesn't work in Firefox, since it is proprietary method that only works in Internet Explorer. You can fix the issue in Firefox by appending the link to the document body and triggering click afterwards. I'll make a code example to answer your question.

Comment: alright waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var fileName = 'Post-ITIE.jpg';

if ('msToBlob' in canvas) { // IE10+
  var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
  navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
} else {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL());
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
  a.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

It does a couple of thing differently than the code originally provided:

- It checks if the `msToBlob` method is present to support downloading the file in Internet Explorer.
- It adds a `target=blank` to the link element. This makes sure that the image is displayed, even if the browser doesn't support the `download` attribute.
- It adds the link to the document so that the `.click()` actually works in Firefox and removes it afterwards.